# PHP str_replace() for $category['name'] substrings

Tags: php, substring, str-replace

I am echoing out category names for a menu with:

```
<?php echo $category['name']; ?>
```

where 'name' is an array :

Purina Dog Food, Purina Cat Food, Eukanuba Dog Food, Eukanuba Cat Food,...

I can't figure out how to use `str_replace();` to stop the substrings 'Dog Food' and 'Cat Food' from appearing in the menu.

I tried this without success (of course):

```
<?php echo $category['name']; str_replace("Cat Food", "", $category['name']); ?>
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: is $category['name'] a array or does it actually echo 'Purina Dog Food' and 'Purina Cat Food'

Comment: it's an array. Just edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use John Conde's answer or you could use something like:

```
$category['name'] = preg_replace('/ (Cat|Dog) Food/i', '', $category['name']);
```

Which should replace all occurrences with Cat/Dog Food and you might want to loop again to eliminate duplicate names.
Sample: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kj883M

Comment: or <?php echo preg_replace('/ (Cat|Dog) Food/i', '', $category['name']); ?>   for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

`str_replace()` can take an array as its first parameter and replace them with a single value (second parameter).

```
str_replace(array('Cat Food', 'Dog Food'), '', $category['name']);
```

Comment: you forgot a ' at the end of Dog Food

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [strtr](http://php.net/strtr);

```
$s = 'Cat Food, Dog Food';
$r = $category['name'];
echo strtr($s, array(
    'Cat Food' => $r,
    'Dog Food' => $r
));
```